# How to make user screens in Android and how to navigate between different screens

Tags: android

In Android, how can I make user screens and how to navigate between them?

Comment: Refer this tutorial from Google. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make your user screen with the xml layout...

and for navigate..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentclass.this, destinationclass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```